# the server should respond with a 404 error, not a 302 redirect to 404 error page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

My page is not available it is showing 302 redirect to 404 error.Instead of directly going to 404 error page. After changing the value of "redirectHttp10Compatible" property as false in spring-mvc-config.xml. It is now working as 303 redirected to 404 . Can anyone please tell ,how can I redirect my unavailable page to 404 directly?

Answer (score 0):

What type of page is not available? Possible page types are: ContentPage, ProductPage, CategoryPage etc. Depending on the URL you are accessing, a different controller is called. The controller then decides what to do with the request. Some controllers do a redirect to a URL like "/404" or "/notFound" instead of returning the error page.

Have a look at ProductPageController, CategoryPageController, DefaultPageController etc.